# RabbitMQ catch queue length exception

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, polly

## Background info

I have a system of three micro services.

The first one is called form a powershell script which informs the system that data is ready for extraction from the database for customer 1.   This is inserted into Queue 1.

The second microservice is listening to queue one when it gets info that it is ready.  It connects to the database and begins to fill queue 2 with the data that needs to be sent.

The third microservice is listing to queue 2 and begins to send the data queued to a third party gate way.   (there will be a limitation place on my system as to how many requests i can make to the gateway I have not been told what that is yet as the gateway server is still underdevelopment as well.)

My issue is that queue 2 can be overloaded for serval reasons

1. serval customers ready at once.
2. the gateway being down and the queue not being emptied.

So I am trying to ensure that if queue 2 is full that the second microservice nacks back to queue 1 that it needs to try again.  My worry is that if microservice two nacks back to queue one (doesn't remove it) that it will instantly try again.   I need to implement some kind of back off here.  I am wondering if maybe I should implement exponential back off in microservice two rather than nacking it back.  But at some point i need to stop it if the gateway is down for a couple of days I'm not sure if this should just keep trying forever.

I have started to implement something checks how much room there is in queue two before it starts to load it.

I have used RabbitMQ before but I have never been the one to set everything up.

## What I have done

I have configured a queue with a very low limit of 10, I am trying to test Polly retry and circuit breaker.

[image: queue properties]

As you can see its set with a max length of ten.

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"x-max-length", _queueSettings.MaxLength},
                {"x-overflow", "reject-publish"},
                {"x-max-length-bytes", _queueSettings.MaxLengthInBytes}
            };
using var channel = _connection.CreateModel();
channel.QueueDeclare(queue: _queueSettings.Name, 
      durable: _queueSettings.Durable, exclusive: false,
      autoDelete: false, arguments: args);
```

The issue is that when it runs it doesn't fail.  It just doesn't add anything to the queue and everything is probably just getting dumped into dead letter.  I need it to return to my application so that I can set it to stop sending (circuit breaker) until the queue  has been cleared so that I can add things again.  Other wise I am just loosing requests.

## send without Polly

```
channel.ConfirmSelect();
// uses a 5 second timeout
channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            
var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
properties.DeliveryMode = 2; // persistent

_logger.LogTrace("Publishing report to RabbitMQ: {RecordId}", 
     @jsonReportData.RecordId);

channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", 
     routingKey: _queueSettings.Name, 
     basicProperties: properties, body: body);
```

## send with Polly

```
var policy = RetryPolicy
    .Handle<OperationInterruptedException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(1, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
        (ex, time) =>
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(ex,
                "Could not publish RecordId: {RecordId} after {Timeout}s ({ExceptionMessage})",
                @jsonReportData.RecordId,
                $"{time.TotalSeconds:n1}", ex.Message);
        });

channel.ConfirmSelect();
// uses a 5 second timeout
channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

policy.Execute(() =>
{
    var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    properties.DeliveryMode = 2; // persistent

    _logger.LogTrace("Publishing report to RabbitMQ: {RecordId}", 
       @jsonReportData.RecordId);

    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", 
         routingKey: _queueSettings.Name, 
         basicProperties: properties, body: body);
});
```

I swearer it was throwing an exception the last time I tried adding the max length but now it just stops at 10 and ignores everting else.

## listen

I tried adding a listener as well and it didn't help either Im not getting any information back from Rabbit after publishing to the queue.

```
channel.ConfirmSelect();
channel.BasicAcks += (sender, ea) =>
{
    // code when message is confirmed
    int i = 1;
};
channel.BasicNacks += (sender, ea) =>
{
    int i = 1;
};
```

Comment: Let's forget Polly for a second. How do you determine that the operation should be retried?

Comment: I have a version which is catching the channel.BasicNacks.   I believe the only cause of a publish nack would be the queue being overloaded.   The issue being what to do from there.   Do i try to send it again hoping that the queue is no logger overloaded, this being the reason for using Polly to retry a few times.

Comment: I haven't used RabbitMq a while, but if I remember correctly there is a flag bit for requeue in case of Nack. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Queue 1 listener feeds Queue2 my issues is Queue2 getting overloaded so what i would like to do is Reject Queue 1 and have it wait until there is room in Queue 2 for its requests.    If i Nack back Queue 1 and tell it not to delete it  its going to try to run again and i am afraid of it going into some kind of spam loop

Comment: So, with nack-ing do you want to enforce back-pressure?

Comment: yes i think thats the best idea i have currently

Comment: @DalmTo Apologize for the late response. I think you are mixing two things. Either use [back-pressure](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#bac) with retry or circuit breaker with retry. In the former case the service side tells you whenever it can't handle the request. In your case that's where you use `nack`. So, the consumer already knows that the service is under heavy load and it can act based on this, for example retry with exponential backoff. That's there is no need here to use circuit breaker.

Comment: In the latter case the [circuit breaker](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#cir) determines that the downstream is healthy or not. It does that by examining the successive / consecutive requests' response and if a certain threshold is reached then it will consider the service as temporarily unavailable. So, during the transient failure it will block all requests against the downstream system. In other words any retries during this period will be rejected with a `BrokenCircuitException`.  Can you see the differences between the two approaches?

Comment: I suspect that you are right I may be going about this the wrong way.   I have added a bit of background information at the top of the question with exactly what the issue is i am trying to solve with this.

Comment: After I have read the background information I'm confused. With queuing you are decoupling the producer from consumer side. So, producer can be run faster than consumer(s). If you have a rate-limiting/throttling in a downstream system then that is another problem. I think you should not bind your outgoing requests rate to your inbound  requests rate. Or do I miss the point?

Comment: This is a country wide system i am not to worried about the limit that will be placed upon my system.   I just need to take note of it because they have told me they will be enforcing flood protection.     This system needs to handle the gateway being down  That's what i am currently worried about.   I cant loose anything in the queue as this is time critical data.   It needs to be sent as soon as the gateway comes back up again.

Comment: So if queue 2 is overloaded microservice two needs to stop trying to load to it and wait until queue 2 is emptied by microservice 3 as soon as the gateway is up again.

Comment: @DalmTo If you want to do that I would suggest to take a look at this: [Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry). Via this library you can define a [max retry threshold with exponential backoff](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry#wait-and-retry-with-exponential-back-off) easily.

Comment: @DalmTo Does the suggested library solve your problem or do you need further information / help?